# Fetch the data of a variable from a URL into a form action

Tags: php, url

I am trying to write a code were i need to fetch the data inside a variable from a URL into a form "action" but the variable data in form action's URL IS not visible and henceforth not able to move on,this is the little amount of code i can present, please help me on this issue, pardon me i went wrong somewhere.

**URL.php**

```
http://www.***.com/***/pro_ppl.php?g_name=12&g_name=My%20group
```

**formaction.php**

```
echo '<form id="form" name ="form" method = "POST" action="move_ppl.php?g_id = "' . $_GET['g_name'] . '" class="wizard-big" autocomplete = "off" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your action attribute to

```
action="move_ppl.php?g_id ='. $_GET['g_name'] . '"
```

Remove **"** quote after `?g_id`

Comment: Sir if wont mind shall i ask you an another question..!

Comment: sure brother @Hari

Comment: thanks you sir, question is how can i pass the variable "g_id" in a header like inside "header('Location: pro_ppl.php');"  from "move_ppl.php?g_id%20=My%20group" this URL

Comment: you mean u want to redirect to same page without id ?

Comment: yes sir, but how can i make the header to fetch the data from "move_ppl.php?g_id%20=My%20group" URL? like  "header('Location: pro_ppl.php?g_name=$g_id ');"

Comment: are u want whole data after save db ?

Comment: then you have to also pass your primary id of row in header which store in db ... then based on id you get the data of your submitting form there is mysqli_inserted_id() function which fetch the last inserted row in db after inserting